# fastest way to find matching pattern

Tags: search-algorithms, search-problem

I have several series of integers (vectors) that could be plotted at equal distances apart:

```
1: [0,1,2,1,5,3,5,7,4,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,8,1,3,1,3,8,4,3,5,1,3,8,3,4,1,8,8,6...] 
2: [5,3,7,4,2,3,4,1,2,11,5,3,15,7,4,13,7,2,13,8,9,11,1,19,11,8,11,16,11...] 
...
n: [40,31,32,41,45,43,45,57,54,42,53,44,53,44,53,35,31,33,8,3,4,1,8,8,6...]
```

I need to find an algorithm that finds the closest relative pattern within each of these series.

For instance, imagine I had a pattern such as `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0` (steady rise from 0 to 9 then a steady fall back to 0). I need to rank order the top patterns anywhere within these series to this pattern.

I might find in series number 37 this exact pattern, except the numbers, are in 100's: `0,100,200,300,400...900...100,0` Well that would be a very close match because it goes in the same direction and by the same proportions. The other thing is, that pattern might be buried deep within the 37th series, say it starts at index 55,000 or something.

I understand that this is quite vague but I don't know where to start. What is the best algorithm for finding these patterns fast? what is the best data structure to preprocess my data into?

I thought, perhaps I should get a percentage of change between every element in every series, then save that and query against that when I find the right algorithm. Then I thought, well if I'm gonna preprocess them, why don't I boil each series down to a function of some kind, perhaps that would be even faster to search...

Surely others have run into this kind of problem. What might they have called it?